# Unique Div not slideToggling on specific icon click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is the html code of the clicking icon:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stat-item remark" id='id' rel='msg_id' title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>
```

Here is the html for the div to load

```
<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer">
  <p>Loading the list</p>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery which i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".stat-item.remark").on("click", function( e ) {
    $(".post-footer").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

My project consists of displaying several divs(extraction from db using php's `fetcharray` loop function)with different contents inside it. But the post-footer class of the div is same in every div i could see,the icon . My problem is when i click the  icon i can all the class named 'post-footer' is slideToggling. How can i make them slideToggle independently with each icon click(class="stat-item remark") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data-*` attributes by storing `data-id` of the related `post-footer` in your links like:

```
<a href="" class="stat-item remark" data-msg-id="<?php echo $omsg_id;?>" title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>  

<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer-<?php echo $omsg_id;?>">
  <p>Loading the list</p>
</div>
```

Then on click get the `data-id` attribute and target the related `post_footer` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".stat-item.remark").on("click", function( e ) 
  {
      e.preventDefault();

      var post_footer_id = "#post-footer-"+$(this).data('msg-id');

      $(post_footer_id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".stat-item.remark").on("click", function( e ) {
    var post_footer_id = "#post-footer-"+$(this).data('id');
    $(post_footer_id).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stat-item remark" data-id='1' title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>  
<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer-1">
  <p>Loading the list</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stat-item remark" data-id='2' title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>  
<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer-2">
  <p>Loading the list</p>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stat-item remark" data-id='3' title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>  
<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer-3">
  <p>Loading the list</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what should be the rel value for each <a></a> ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using it? it's not necessary.. if you want to store `msg_id` somewhere it'll be better to store it in `data-msg-id` attribute.

Comment: yes i want to attach msg_id coming for each invidual posts from db

Comment: i want to work exactly what u displayed in the demo. unfortunately its not working . But i am confident your solution will work

Comment: So replace the `rel` by `data-msg-id`... try to add an `alert(post_footer_id)` to make sure that you're getting the right `data-id` from the link.

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stat-item remark" data-msg-id="<?php echo $omsg_id;?>"  title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>  does it luk this ?

Comment: yah its different for each posts

Comment: Ok check my update using `<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer-<?php echo $omsg_id;?>">`.. and in js also we'll use the msg id.

Answer (score 0):

if the link and the div are next to each other do a `next()`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stat-item remark" id='<?php echo $omsg_id;?>'rel='<?php echo $msg_id;?>' title='Give your Remarks on it'>
  <i class="fa fa-comments-o icon"></i>
</a>  
<div class="post-footer" id="post-footer">
  <p>Loading the list</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".stat-item.remark").on("click", function(e) {
          $(this).next(".post-footer").slideToggle();
        });
});
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar what exactly are you saying?